# zRSSFeed Error Handling Issue

Tags: rss, feed

I am using the zRSSFeed plugin with jQuery to display latest news from an RSS feed.

This works well, even with jQuery 1.9.1 (docs state support up to 1.7) and the problem I have exists regardless of which jQuery version I am using.

If an RSS url fails to return a success, I can invoke both 'showerror' and 'errormessage' which is great only if the feed doesn't load for whatever reason.

However, I have found a problem where if an RSS feed is empty - because the news page has removed all articles from the feed for whatever reason - the showerror/errormessage is not used.

I have tried various methods to overcome this shortfall, including:-

```
if(feeds.entries.length < 0) {
$('.mydiv').appendTo("no news articles for now");
}
```

This fails, the page where the RSS feed should appear is left blank, with the exception of the list elements the plugin creates, note the ul element is empty:-

```
<div class="rssBody" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 126px;"><ul style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></ul></div>
```

Any suitably minded genius able to work this one out?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted more code.
Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
$(element).rssfeed(fsrc,
            {
                //zRSSfeed options, bla bla bla
                linktarget: "_blank",
                sort: "title",
                sortasc: true,
                snippet: false,
                content: true,
                media: true,
                showerror: true
            },
            function (e) {
                //check if element's content is empty
                $('.rssFeed', e).each(function (i) {
                  var cont = $(".rssFeed .rssBody").html();
                  if(cont.lenght == 0 || cont == undefined)
                  { return false; }
                });
```

});

Comment: As an example, see here:- http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/world-cup/2014/rss.xml - note the feed does not provide a 404 error, but it's empty (for whatever bizarre reason). I was wondering if there is any callback of sorts that I could implement, there is a var in the zRSSFeed plugin which populates 'feeds.entries.length' therefore I had assumed if a check could be made on whether feeds.entries.length equals zero and zero-only, then showerror.

Comment: @GrantG I don't think there is. zRSSFeed uses a getJSON method which doesn't return any errors. Therefore I think your best option is to perform a check after some time - setTimeout(isUlEmpty, 1000) - and then show your error message.